# submitting various form values in rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

below is part of the table containing form. However, in this case, the submit buttons are drawn for each raw, thereby user should click one by one. However, I'm trying to change with one button submission.

```
<tbody>
  <% sum= @movies.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum+x.ticket_count }
     cnt = 0 %>
  <% @movies.each_with_index do |movie, idx| %>
      <tr id="theater_<%= movie.id %>">
        <td><%= idx+1 %></td>
        <td><%= movie.title %></td>
        <% if @matchables[movie.title] != 0
           t = movie.title %>
          <td><img src="<%= @matchables[t].poster %>" width="100" /></td>
          <td><%= @matchables[t].title  %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_tag(save_movies_admin_theaters_path, method: 'get') do %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :tid, movie.id %>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:nid, (@matchables[movie.title] != 0 ? @matchables[movie.title].naver_id : ""), class: 'input-mini') %></td>
            <td><%= submit_tag('submit' , class: "btn btn-primary") %></td>
        <% end %>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so I thought about using

```
<input type='text' name='mid' class='movie' value=''/>
```

to get all values for rows, and send it through via `ajax` form with js function. But I'm really unfamiliar with `js` with `rails` So if there's something guide to send multiple values in this format, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make form tag on `tbody` level.
Also use `<%= fields_for "movies[]", movie do |mv| %>` for each movie.

```
<tbody>
<%= form_tag(save_movies_admin_theaters_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <% sum= @movies.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum+x.ticket_count }
     cnt = 0 %>
  <% @movies.each_with_index do |movie, idx| %>
    <%= fields_for "movies[]", idx do |mv| %>
       <tr id="theater_<%= movie.id %>">
        <td><%= idx+1 %></td>
        <td><%= movie.title %></td>
        <% if @matchables[movie.title] != 0
           t = movie.title %>
          <td><img src="<%= @matchables[t].poster %>" width="100" /></td>
          <td><%= @matchables[t].title  %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
        <% end %>
        <%= mv.hidden_field :tid, movie.id %>
        <td><%= mv.text_field :nid, (@matchables[movie.title] != 0 ? @matchables[movie.title].naver_id : ""), class: 'input-mini') %></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <tr><%= submit_tag('submit' , class: "btn btn-primary") %></tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

After submission, you can read params in this format.

```
params[:movies][idx]
```

Comment: I was not able to get with params[:movies][0] like this. Is there anything you've missed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag(save_movies_admin_theaters_path, method: 'post') do %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :tid, movie.id %>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:nid, (@matchables[movie.title] != 0 ? @matchables[movie.title].naver_id : ""), class: 'input-mini') %></td>
            <td><%= submit_tag('submit' , class: "btn btn-primary") %></td>
        <% end %>
```

Write 'post' instead of 'get'.Can you please be clear in what is your exact question

Comment: In this case, I'm making numbers of submit buttons, but I want to make it as one button submit.